# What is an efficient way to develop Airflow plugins? (without restarting the webserver for each change)

Tags: flask, airflow

I am looking for an efficient way to develop plugins within Airflow.

Current behavior: I change something in Python files e.g. test_plugin.py, reload the page in browser and nothing happens until I restart the webserver. This is most annoying and time consuming.

Desired behavior: I change something in Python files and the change is reflected after reloading the app in the browser.

As Airflow is based on Flask and in Flask the desired behavior is achievable by running Flask in debug mode (export FLASK_DEBUG=1, then start Flask app): Can I achieve the Flask behavior somehow in Airflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was indeed a bug with the Airflow CLI's `webserver --debug` mode; future versions will have the expected behavior.

---

Issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-5867

PR: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6517

---

In order to run Airflow with live reloading, run the following command (10.7+):

```sh
$ airflow webserver --debug
```

---

In contrast to the code modification suggested by @herrjeh42, make sure that your configuration **does not** include `unit_test_mode = True` in order to enable reloading.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can force reloading the python code by starting the airflow webserver in debug & reload mode. As of Airflow 1.10.5 I had to modify *airflow/bin/cli.py* (from my opinion the line is buggy).

old:

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False if app.config['TESTING'] else True,
```

new:

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True if json.loads(app.config['TESTING'].lower()) else False,
```

Change in airflow.cfg

```
unit_test_mode = True
```

Start the webserver with

```
airflow webserver -d
```